# How many ways can 5 different jobs be assigned to 3 different employees so that each employee is assigned at least 1 job?

Tags: probability

Solution given made use of the inclusion and exclusion principle: 
Number of ways = 3^5 - (3 x 2^5) + 3

I don't quite get the solution :/ 
Can't we just assign each of the employee one job and then assign the remaining 2 jobs to the 3 employees like so: C(5,1) x C(4,1) x C(3,1) x C(4,2)?
( C(4,2) is the number of ways of arranging 2 bars and the remaining 2 jobs)

Comment: I don't get where the C(4,1) comes from. Can you give me more detail?

Comment: Your proposed solution overcounts the possibilities.  For instance if employee A gets jobs $1$ and $2$, these could have been with job $1$ being the first job and $2$ being the extra job; or vice versa.

Comment: @wece It should be C(4,2) cos C(3-1+2,2). Sorry for the typo :/

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, could you explain a little more?

Comment: to rephrase @paw88789 the job are different but you don't need to look at the order in which they are given. For the solution the $3^5$ comes from the number of way to assign 5 jobs on 3 employees. you have to substract from that the arrangement that leave (at least) an employee jobless: 3 possible employee jobless and $2^5$ way to arrange the job on the other employees

Comment: @wece Got it, thanks! :)